# Fill select with object datasource

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Controller:

```
$scope.obj = {
    "category": {
        "value": "1",
        "synonym": ""
    },
    "name": {
        "value": "2",
        "synonym": ""
    }
};
```

I have html like this:

```
<select
     ng-model="model",
     ng-options="value.value as key for (key , value) in obj",
     bs-select>
</select>
```

I want to get this result:

```
<option value="1"> category </option>
<option value="2"> name </option>
```

But i get this:

```
<option value="category"> category </option>
<option value="name"> name </option>
```

Can you help me to find a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. The drop down list is a bit confusing since you should get the value by accessing from the **model** rather than from DOM. So whatever rendered in HTML doesn't matter.

Here is one example ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4U2qk/)), when you change the drop down, the actual value will be passed in. Though it looks a bit different in the rendered HTML, this is the nature of Angularjs being a self-contained scope for 2-way data binding.

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
        "category": {
            "value": "1",
            "synonym": ""
        },
        "name": {
            "value": "2",
            "synonym": ""
        }
    };

    $scope.model = "1";

    $scope.$watch('model', function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);
    });
}
```